# Is there a way to run Entity Framework migrations before Hosted Services start

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

When I created my .NET Core 5 application, I ran EF migrations by executing the migration code at the top of my Startup.Configure (...) method:

```
public class Startup 
{
    . . .
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
        {
             ApplicationDbContext context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
             context.Database.Migrate();
        }
        . . .
    }
}
```

This all worked well enough until I recently added some Hosted Services that rely on the DB and changes applied by the migrations. Now, if I have migrations that need to be applied before the hosted services start, my app crashes at startup because the hosted services are starting before the migrations run.

Is there a way to fix this? Is there a way to have the migrations run before the hosted services are started?

Comment: IMHO perform the migration in your own `HostedService`, just make sure to register it first.

Comment: That might work if you only have one hosted service but what if you have more than that all rely on the DB?

Comment: `HostedServices` are started in series, the service provider returns them in the same order they were registered. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e18d25e1a81d359097371615ff1a3407597c0bb3/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L51

Answer (score 2):

After some mucking around, this solution seems to work, although I don't know enough about the .NET Core Framework to determine if this will be a problem:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory = host.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
        using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            ApplicationDbContext context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            context.Database.Migrate();
        }
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddConsole();
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Comment: This would have been my suggested approach. Calling the migration before calling `Run` will ensure that the migration is done before the hosted services are started.